# Facebook login Integration in windows phone 8.1 silverlight

Tags: c#, facebook, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am new windows phone 8.1 development, i want to integrate facebook login page and update status in through my app in windows phone 8.1 silverlight application. I search alot but nothing found for silverlight app. i add Facebook reference from Nuget package and add three classes here is my code

FacebookHelper.cs

```
    using Facebook;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Security.Authentication.Web;

namespace FaceBookWp8._1.Helpers
{
    public class FaceBookHelper
    {
        FacebookClient _fb = new FacebookClient();
        readonly Uri _callbackUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
        readonly Uri _loginUrl;
        private const string FacebookAppId = "1085047434841730";//Enter your FaceBook App ID here       
        //private const string FacebookPermissions = "user_about_me,read_stream,publish_stream";
        private const string FacebookPermissions = "user_about_me,publish_actions";
        public string AccessToken
        {
            get { return _fb.AccessToken; }
        }

        public FaceBookHelper()
        {
            _loginUrl = _fb.GetLoginUrl(new
                    {
                        client_id = FacebookAppId,
                        redirect_uri = _callbackUri.AbsoluteUri,
                        scope = FacebookPermissions,
                        display = "popup",
                        response_type = "token"
                    });
            Debug.WriteLine(_callbackUri);//This is useful for fill Windows Store ID in Facebook WebSite
        }
        private void ValidateAndProccessResult(WebAuthenticationResult result)
        {
            if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                var responseUri = new Uri(result.ResponseData.ToString());
                var facebookOAuthResult = _fb.ParseOAuthCallbackUrl(responseUri);

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(facebookOAuthResult.Error))
                    _fb.AccessToken = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
                else
                {//error de acceso denegado por cancelación en página
                }
            }
            else if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
            {// error de http
            }
            else
            {
                _fb.AccessToken = null;//Keep null when user signout from facebook
            }
        }
        public void LoginAndContinue()
        {
            WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(_loginUrl);
        }
        public void ContinueAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
        {
            ValidateAndProccessResult(args.WebAuthenticationResult);
        }
    }
}
```

ContinuationManager.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;


namespace FacebookAppSL
{
    class ContinuationManager
    {
        public void ContinueWith(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame == null)
                return;

            switch (args.Kind)
            {
                case ActivationKind.PickFileContinuation:
                    break;
                case ActivationKind.PickFolderContinuation:
                    break;
                case ActivationKind.PickSaveFileContinuation:
                    break;
                case ActivationKind.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation:
                    var continuator = rootFrame.Content as IWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuable;
                    if (continuator != null)
                        continuator.ContinueWithWebAuthenticationBroker((WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs)args);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    interface IWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuable
    {
        void ContinueWithWebAuthenticationBroker(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args);
    }
}
```

SuspensionManager.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;


namespace FacebookAppSL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// SuspensionManager captures global session state to simplify process lifetime management
    /// for an application.  Note that session state will be automatically cleared under a variety
    /// of conditions and should only be used to store information that would be convenient to
    /// carry across sessions, but that should be discarded when an application crashes or is
    /// upgraded.
    /// </summary>
    internal sealed class SuspensionManager
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, object> _sessionState = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        private static List<Type> _knownTypes = new List<Type>();
        private const string sessionStateFilename = "_sessionState.xml";

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides access to global session state for the current session.  This state is
        /// serialized by <see cref="SaveAsync"/> and restored by
        /// <see cref="RestoreAsync"/>, so values must be serializable by
        /// <see cref="DataContractSerializer"/> and should be as compact as possible.  Strings
        /// and other self-contained data types are strongly recommended.
        /// </summary>
        public static Dictionary<string, object> SessionState
        {
            get { return _sessionState; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// List of custom types provided to the <see cref="DataContractSerializer"/> when
        /// reading and writing session state.  Initially empty, additional types may be
        /// added to customize the serialization process.
        /// </summary>
        public static List<Type> KnownTypes
        {
            get { return _knownTypes; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save the current <see cref="SessionState"/>.  Any <see cref="Frame"/> instances
        /// registered with <see cref="RegisterFrame"/> will also preserve their current
        /// navigation stack, which in turn gives their active <see cref="Page"/> an opportunity
        /// to save its state.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An asynchronous task that reflects when session state has been saved.</returns>
        public static async Task SaveAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                // Save the navigation state for all registered frames
                foreach (var weakFrameReference in _registeredFrames)
                {
                    Frame frame;
                    if (weakFrameReference.TryGetTarget(out frame))
                    {
                        SaveFrameNavigationState(frame);
                    }
                }

                // Serialize the session state synchronously to avoid asynchronous access to shared
                // state
                MemoryStream sessionData = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), _knownTypes);
                serializer.WriteObject(sessionData, _sessionState);

                // Get an output stream for the SessionState file and write the state asynchronously
                StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(sessionStateFilename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    sessionData.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    await sessionData.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new SuspensionManagerException(e);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Restores previously saved <see cref="SessionState"/>.  Any <see cref="Frame"/> instances
        /// registered with <see cref="RegisterFrame"/> will also restore their prior navigation
        /// state, which in turn gives their active <see cref="Page"/> an opportunity restore its
        /// state.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sessionBaseKey">An optional key that identifies the type of session.
        /// This can be used to distinguish between multiple application launch scenarios.</param>
        /// <returns>An asynchronous task that reflects when session state has been read.  The
        /// content of <see cref="SessionState"/> should not be relied upon until this task
        /// completes.</returns>
        public static async Task RestoreAsync(String sessionBaseKey = null)
        {
            _sessionState = new Dictionary<String, Object>();

            try
            {
                // Get the input stream for the SessionState file
                StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(sessionStateFilename);
                using (IInputStream inStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
                {
                    // Deserialize the Session State
                    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), _knownTypes);
                    _sessionState = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
                }

                // Restore any registered frames to their saved state
                foreach (var weakFrameReference in _registeredFrames)
                {
                    Frame frame;
                    if (weakFrameReference.TryGetTarget(out frame) && (string)frame.GetValue(FrameSessionBaseKeyProperty) == sessionBaseKey)
                    {
                        frame.ClearValue(FrameSessionStateProperty);
                        RestoreFrameNavigationState(frame);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new SuspensionManagerException(e);
            }
        }

        private static DependencyProperty FrameSessionStateKeyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("_FrameSessionStateKey", typeof(String), typeof(SuspensionManager), null);
        private static DependencyProperty FrameSessionBaseKeyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("_FrameSessionBaseKeyParams", typeof(String), typeof(SuspensionManager), null);
        private static DependencyProperty FrameSessionStateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("_FrameSessionState", typeof(Dictionary<String, Object>), typeof(SuspensionManager), null);
        private static List<WeakReference<Frame>> _registeredFrames = new List<WeakReference<Frame>>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers a <see cref="Frame"/> instance to allow its navigation history to be saved to
        /// and restored from <see cref="SessionState"/>.  Frames should be registered once
        /// immediately after creation if they will participate in session state management.  Upon
        /// registration if state has already been restored for the specified key
        /// the navigation history will immediately be restored.  Subsequent invocations of
        /// <see cref="RestoreAsync"/> will also restore navigation history.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="frame">An instance whose navigation history should be managed by
        /// <see cref="SuspensionManager"/></param>
        /// <param name="sessionStateKey">A unique key into <see cref="SessionState"/> used to
        /// store navigation-related information.</param>
        /// <param name="sessionBaseKey">An optional key that identifies the type of session.
        /// This can be used to distinguish between multiple application launch scenarios.</param>
        public static void RegisterFrame(Frame frame, String sessionStateKey, String sessionBaseKey = null)
        {
            if (frame.GetValue(FrameSessionStateKeyProperty) != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Frames can only be registered to one session state key");
            }

            if (frame.GetValue(FrameSessionStateProperty) != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Frames must be either be registered before accessing frame session state, or not registered at all");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionBaseKey))
            {
                frame.SetValue(FrameSessionBaseKeyProperty, sessionBaseKey);
                sessionStateKey = sessionBaseKey + "_" + sessionStateKey;
            }

            // Use a dependency property to associate the session key with a frame, and keep a list of frames whose
            // navigation state should be managed
            frame.SetValue(FrameSessionStateKeyProperty, sessionStateKey);
            _registeredFrames.Add(new WeakReference<Frame>(frame));

            // Check to see if navigation state can be restored
            RestoreFrameNavigationState(frame);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disassociates a <see cref="Frame"/> previously registered by <see cref="RegisterFrame"/>
        /// from <see cref="SessionState"/>.  Any navigation state previously captured will be
        /// removed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="frame">An instance whose navigation history should no longer be
        /// managed.</param>
        public static void UnregisterFrame(Frame frame)
        {
            // Remove session state and remove the frame from the list of frames whose navigation
            // state will be saved (along with any weak references that are no longer reachable)
            SessionState.Remove((String)frame.GetValue(FrameSessionStateKeyProperty));
            _registeredFrames.RemoveAll((weakFrameReference) =>
            {
                Frame testFrame;
                return !weakFrameReference.TryGetTarget(out testFrame) || testFrame == frame;
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides storage for session state associated with the specified <see cref="Frame"/>.
        /// Frames that have been previously registered with <see cref="RegisterFrame"/> have
        /// their session state saved and restored automatically as a part of the global
        /// <see cref="SessionState"/>.  Frames that are not registered have transient state
        /// that can still be useful when restoring pages that have been discarded from the
        /// navigation cache.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Apps may choose to rely on <see cref="NavigationHelper"/> to manage
        /// page-specific state instead of working with frame session state directly.</remarks>
        /// <param name="frame">The instance for which session state is desired.</param>
        /// <returns>A collection of state subject to the same serialization mechanism as
        /// <see cref="SessionState"/>.</returns>
        public static Dictionary<String, Object> SessionStateForFrame(Frame frame)
        {
            var frameState = (Dictionary<String, Object>)frame.GetValue(FrameSessionStateProperty);

            if (frameState == null)
            {
                var frameSessionKey = (String)frame.GetValue(FrameSessionStateKeyProperty);
                if (frameSessionKey != null)
                {
                    // Registered frames reflect the corresponding session state
                    if (!_sessionState.ContainsKey(frameSessionKey))
                    {
                        _sessionState[frameSessionKey] = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
                    }
                    frameState = (Dictionary<String, Object>)_sessionState[frameSessionKey];
                }
                else
                {
                    // Frames that aren't registered have transient state
                    frameState = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
                }
                frame.SetValue(FrameSessionStateProperty, frameState);
            }
            return frameState;
        }

        private static void RestoreFrameNavigationState(Frame frame)
        {
            var frameState = SessionStateForFrame(frame);
            if (frameState.ContainsKey("Navigation"))
            {
                frame.SetNavigationState((String)frameState["Navigation"]);
            }
        }

        private static void SaveFrameNavigationState(Frame frame)
        {
            var frameState = SessionStateForFrame(frame);
            frameState["Navigation"] = frame.GetNavigationState();
        }
    }
    public class SuspensionManagerException : Exception
    {
        public SuspensionManagerException()
        {
        }

        public SuspensionManagerException(Exception e)
            : base("SuspensionManager failed", e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 using Facebook;
using FaceBookWp8._1.Helpers;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Security.Authentication.Web;
using Windows.UI.Popups;


// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=391641

namespace FacebookAppSL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, IWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuable
    {
        readonly Uri _loginUrl;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }
        FaceBookHelper ObjFBHelper = new FaceBookHelper();
        private void BtnFaceBookLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ObjFBHelper.LoginAndContinue();
        }
        FacebookClient fbclient = new FacebookClient();
        public async void ContinueWithWebAuthenticationBroker(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
        {
            ObjFBHelper.ContinueAuthentication(args);
            if (ObjFBHelper.AccessToken != null)
            {
                fbclient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(ObjFBHelper.AccessToken);

                //Fetch facebook UserProfile:
                dynamic result = await fbclient.GetTaskAsync("me");
                string id = result.id;
                string email = result.email;
                string FBName = result.name;

                //Format UserProfile:
                GetUserProfilePicture(id);
                TxtUserProfile.Text = FBName;
                StckPnlProfile_Layout.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                BtnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                BtnLogout.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                StckPnlProfile_Layout.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

        }
        private void GetUserProfilePicture(string UserID)
        {
            string profilePictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type={1}&access_token={2}", UserID, "square", ObjFBHelper.AccessToken);
            picProfile.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(profilePictureUrl));
        }
        private async void BtnFaceBookPost_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var postParams = new
            {
                name = "Facebook Post Testing from FsdSolutions.",
                caption = "WindowsPhone 8.1 FaceBook Integration.",
                link = "http://www.fsdsolutions.com/",
                description = TxtStatusMsg.Text,
                //picture = "http://facebooksdk.net/assets/img/logo75x75.png"
            };
            try
            {
                dynamic fbPostTaskResult = await fbclient.PostTaskAsync("/me/feed", postParams);
                var responseresult = (IDictionary<string, object>)fbPostTaskResult;
                //MessageDialog SuccessMsg = new MessageDialog("Message posted sucessfully on facebook wall");
                //await SuccessMsg.ShowAsync();
                MessageBox.Show("Message posted sucessfully on facebook wall");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageDialog ErrMsg = new MessageDialog("Error Ocuured!");

            }
        }
        Uri _logoutUrl;
        private async void BtnFaceBookLogout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _logoutUrl = fbclient.GetLogoutUrl(new
            {
                next = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
                access_token = ObjFBHelper.AccessToken
            });
            WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(_logoutUrl);
            BtnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            BtnLogout.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

I found a problem in these lines in windows phone 8.1 silverlight in ContinuationManager.cs

```
var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
```

in SuspensionManager.cs

```
frame.SetNavigationState((String)frameState["Navigation"]);
frameState["Navigation"] = frame.GetNavigationState();
```

and In MainPage.xaml.cs

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

Please tell me the alternative of these lines to remove errors.